# Pycharm Intellisense for custom class surprising behavior

Tags: python, pycharm

Recently, I was using pycharm to implement some simple algorithm. 
But I found a rather surprising fact.

Here is my code

```
def main():
n = Node(2)
n.nextNode=Node(1)

def TraverseNodes(node):
    if node.nextNode = None
        print(node.num)
    else:
        print(node.num)
        TraverseNodes(node.nextNode)

class Node():
    nextNode = None
    num = None
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
    def appendNext(self,next):
        self.nextNode=next

main()
```

As far as I know, python is a dynamic type language, which means the type is interpreted at runtime.

So pycharm should't know what type does the "node" parameter in TrasverseNode method belongs to.

But when I actually wrote the details of the method, the intellisense seemed to be able to infer the type is node ?!
[image]

( I tried different parameter name , only "node" could lead to this behavior , others can't. Does this means pycharm can infer the type by the similarity in names ? )

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possibly the fact that `nextNode` only ever references an object of type `Node`?  What if you add a line like `n.nextNode = 'some string'`?

Comment: I modify the class declaration  to  nextNode = "test" 
But this situation still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you have a variable and a class with the same name as the variable but capitalized, PyCharm does assume that the variable may be an instance of that class, and suggests the members of this class in the completion popup.

(This only affects completion - for example, it will not show warnings if you access a member which is not defined in this class.)